# By entering any value, the output of error does not change. (try , catch ,finally)

Tags: javascript, error-handling, dom-events

I just started learning JavaScript and now I have another problem with errors. By entering any value, the output does not change. Please help find my code problem.

```js
function checker(){
      var message, x;
      message = document.getElementById('resault');
      x = document.getElementById('v').Value;

      try {
            if (x == "") throw "empty";
            if (isNaN(x)) throw "not a number"
            x = Number(x);
            if (x < 5) throw "too low"
            if (x > 10) throw "too high"
      }
      catch(err) {
            message.innerHTML= "input is" + err ;   

      }
      finally {
            document.getElementById('v').Value = "it is  used !"
      }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p>input a number between 5 and 10 ! </p> 
  <input type="number" id="v" placeholder="input here!">
  <button onclick="checker()">check my number</button>  
  <p id="resault"></p> 




  <script src="js.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mean that it only shows 'input is not a number' right?. try to change  inputs type to number. Than it should work

Comment: Yes, I mean that, but the problem was not solved by changing the type to number

Comment: change  `x = document.getElementById('v').Value;` to ` `x = document.getElementById('v').value;`

Comment: I can't see the difference between the two

Comment: @M.alizadeh the property `Value` needs to be lowercase = `document.getElementById('v').value`, there is no attribute called `Value`

Comment: Wow, a small problem :/ . Thank you very much for your careful attention. My problem was solved.